# Mosaic Dataset - Gray and White areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic-dataset

I'm trying to add high resolution orthoimagery from the USGS to a mosaic dataset in arcMap. When I "Add rasters to mosaic dataset" most of the rasters load in fine, but some have strips of white area and other places are sort of grey, low contrast. I checked Update Overviews. Please see the image below as an example of the issue. Also, as you zoom in the grey/white areas go away. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Is this over a military base or other critical infrastructure element?  USGS data is downsampled or redacted as appropriate for homeland security purposes.

Comment: I've no idea concerning the grey ones but the white areas could be a result of the maximum downloadable images. Please have a look at the Mosaic Dataset Properties ==> Defaults ==> Download Properties ==> Maximum Number of Items Downloadable per Request

Comment: It is not over any critical infrastructure. The download settings didn't help. I went ahead and built footprints, seamlines, and rebuilt the overviews and all the white/gray areas moved to different locations.

Answer (score 0):

From Esri Technical Support: "The caching process sometimes creates blank and/or white tiles when using Mosaic datasets."

Their recommendation at https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011325 is to bump the number of maximum number of rasters per mosaic dataset from the default of 20 to 100 (right click mosaic dataset > properties > defaults tab > Maximum Number of Rasters per Mosaic). This worked for me for WorldView-2 imagery.

Instead of changing the maximum number of rasters per mosaic default value, clicking the Dynamic Range Adjustment button also worked for me (in Pro this is: highlight mosaic dataset in Contents: Mosaic Layer ribbon > Appearance > DRA (next to Stretch Type).